# Update Java Applet for the User

Tags: java, deployment, applet, auto-update

I am having a hard time figuring out a way to update my applet without having the user going through the hassle of updating their java version. Is there a way to do this? The following the is the applet I am using:

```html
<tr align="left">
<td height="34" colspan="2"><div align="left"><span class="mission style16"><span class="style21">
    <applet code="NCMECbanner.class" codebase="http://banner.missingkids.com/java/" align="baseline" hspace="8" width="342" height="128">
    </applet>
</span></span></div></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

That way would be [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It provides 'auto-update' out of the box, but also allows apps. to take programmatic control of updates.

Comment: can you please provide an example that can give me an idea on how to approach this. I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: *"can you please provide an example"*  An example requires a JNLP, code, digitally signed Jars & a server that can continually mark Jars as 'changed' (some of which is just to test the example).  As such, it is not practical to provide an example.  Note also that SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk.